# Showing $\inf\{m\in\mathbb R:m\in \mathcal A\}>-\infty$

Tags: finance, supremum-and-infimum

> If $\mathcal A:=\{X\in \mathcal X:\rho(X)\le0\}$ with $\rho:\mathcal X(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to\mathbb R$ with $\mathcal X$ being the linear space of bounded functions containing constants, then $$\inf\{m\in\mathbb R:m\in \mathcal A\}>-\infty$$

$\rho$ has some other properties, but I don't know if they're necessary. $\mathcal A$ is closed in $L^{\infty}$ w.r.to $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ norm. So if the infimum is $-\infty$ then since $\mathcal A$ is closed it cannot be in $L^{\infty}$, is it something like this ?

(This is Proposition $4.6$ from the book '' Stochastic Finance'' by Hans Föllmer & Alexander Schied)

EDIT: [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=GOvCDAAAQBAJ&pg=SA3-PA86&dq=stochastic%20finance%20f%C3%B6llmer%20schied%20definition%204.1&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3tom385LVAhXDtBQKHSVCD9MQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=stochastic%20finance%20f%C3%B6llmer%20schied%20definition%204.1&f=false) is the detailed definition of $\rho$

Comment: We clearly need to know more about $\rho$ to say anything. Also, are you implicitly identifying constant functions and real numbers? Don't do that, it is confusing.

Comment: In the beginning, you define $\mathcal A$ as a subset of $L^\infty$.

This means that for each $m\in \mathbb R$, $m\notin \mathcal A$, meaning the question makes no sense.

Comment: You can use argument by contradiction to prove.

Comment: @5xum I am pretty sure they are identifying $m$ and $x \mapsto m$.

Comment: @Ian In the same proposition  a few lines below it is shown that $\inf\{m\in\mathbb R:m+X\in\mathcal A\}=\rho(X)$, then can we not say that $\inf\{m\in\mathbb R:m\in\mathcal A\}=\inf\{m\in\mathbb R:m+0\in\mathcal A\}=\rho(0)$ ?

Comment: That seems to make sense to me assuming $X$ is arbitrary in the first equality in your comment, but is it trivial that $\rho(0)>-\infty$?